# Use babel in Node console

Tags: node.js, console, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I'm running node `4.6.1` and I'd like to get es6/7/8 syntax in the node console as I can get with Babel. I'm able to compile scripts fine with babel, for instance by running

`babel-node ./index.js --presets es2015,stage-0`

but I could not find how to get such syntax support in the console. For instance the node console doesn't understand things like

```
const filter = {...{ foo: 1 }, ...{ bar: 4 } }
```

or all the async/await things.

Comment: Maybe that's because `async`/`await` is ES8 and object spread syntax is still a proposal only, so nothing about ES6/7?

Comment: https://github.com/paulserraino/babel-repl

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the precision, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running scripts with npm, npm loads scripts under `node_modules/.bin` that are not part of the `PATH`. So running

```
$ babel-node --presets es2015,stage-0
```

will fail with

```
-bash: babel-node: command not found
```

but

```
$ node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets es2015,stage-0
```

will work just fine. I'll get a node console where I can do:

```
> const filter = {...{ foo: 1 }, ...{ bar: 4 } }
> filter
{ foo: 1, bar: 4 }
> const a = async () => {}
```